# Bought .dev domain for apache2 server but get certification error on connection

Tags: ssl-certificate, apache2, lets-encrypt, certbot

I have recently bought a google .dev domain for my website. And i am aware that with .dev domain there comes a integrated ssl-certificate.
I have a different website with .net and that works like a charm where i made my own certificate with certbot but i cant get it to work on a .dev domain.
This is the certificate error i get when i connect
[image: cert error]

This is my `/etc/apache2/sites-available/tactocdev.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
            ServerName tactoc.dev
            ServerAdmin tactocstudios@gmail.com
            WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/tactocdev/tactocdev.wsgi
            <Directory /var/www/tactocdev/tactocdev/>
                    Order allow,deny
                    Allow from all
            </Directory>
            Alias /static /var/www/tactocdev/tactocdev/static
            <Directory /var/www/tactocdev/tactocdev/static/>
                    Order allow,deny
                    Allow from all
            </Directory>
            ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
            LogLevel warn
            CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

Answer (score 0):

I switched to linode nameservers which is where i hosts my server and it works now